# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to build a force directed graph in D3. Here is the code for it -

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #FFFF;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #111;
}

</style>
<body>
<h1>Hello there</h1>
<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("copy.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { console.log(d.value); return d.value; });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", function(d) { console.log(d.name); return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works with copy.json file. I just copy pasted the json from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) into that file. I have tried to create my own json by parsing through a txt file. The same code is giving me the error when I use my json file. Here is my json file (part of it) -

```
{
    "nodes":[
            "group": 5, 
            "name": "Nancie"
        }, 
        {
            "group": 5, 
            "name": "Jonell"
        }
    ], 
    "links": [
        {
            "source": 1, 
            "target": 29, 
            "value": 2
        }, 
        {
            "source": 1, 
            "target": 43, 
            "value": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tested this json on jsonlint. Does the newline make a difference? I did read a couple of answer that are there on SO about this but none of them match. My source and target nodes are within range, I have no null values and I have taken care of the case when creating my JSON.

Comment: There is no instance of `weight` in the code you posted?

Comment: @RUJordan - Then how does this code work for the copy.json file? The json I copied from the above mentioned source?

Comment: Are you really only using those two links and nodes?  Because your links are referencing nodes with index 29 and 43, and these will be undefined, so when d3 tries to find the properties of those nodes you will get an error.

Comment: @AmeliaBR - The json file that I have is huge. So I did not copy/paste all of it in the question. I did realize that someone would think that might be the error. So I made a few edits to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Well as it turns out I made a stupid mistake while creating my json file. In the links part of the json the numbering for source starts from 0. Hence for the last element I was exceeding the value. And hence I was getting that error.